# Why does converting this exponent throw a FormatException?

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal, implicit-conversion

Why would this exponent throw a `FormatException` when converted to a decimal using `Decimal.Parse`.

```
String stringValue = "8.83080183680678E-05";
Decimal decimalValue = Decimal.Parse(badValue, NumberStyles.AllowExponent);
```

When the code executes it throws a `FormatException`

> "Input string was not in a correct format."

The code seems to adhere to the [MSDN spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb.aspx): `[ws][$][sign][digits,]digits[.fractional-digits][e[sign]digits][ws]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that the number format also allows for decimals.

```
Decimal.Parse(badValue, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

...which is explained in the documentation for AllowExponent:

> Indicates that the numeric string can be in exponential notation. The AllowExponent flag allows the parsed string to contain an exponent that begins with the "E" or "e" character and that is followed by an optional positive or negative sign and an integer. In other words, it successfully parses strings in the form nnnExx, nnnE+xx, and nnnE-xx. **It does not allow a decimal separator or sign in the significand or mantissa; to allow these elements in the string to be parsed, use the AllowDecimalPoint and AllowLeadingSign flags, or use a composite style that includes these individual flags.**

`NumberStyles.Float` is probably a better choice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

[`NumberStyles.AllowExponent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) doesn't include `AllowDecimalPoint`. You might've wanted to use `NumberStyles.Float`, which includes "AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, AllowLeadingSign, AllowDecimalPoint, and AllowExponent".